# Content must be in column, but form label isn't?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my form I've got fields with labels and fields without a label (i.e. a large textarea). I've given both my label and input fields a background color. Currently, the left margin of the labels differs from the left margin of the input fields.

The [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) says:

> Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows.

But the [horizontal form example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) puts a `<label>` element inside a column:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<label>` element is a column, but it is content itself as well:

[image: http://tweakers.net/ext/f/0ZdJCJDj9IPcreOtIdd1D1Kj/full.png]

An easy way to have the same left margin for labels and inputs is to put the label inside a column, instead of being a column as well. Is that the best solution, or is there another way to have both labels and inputs have the same left margin?

Comment: Please create working fiddle to see

Comment: @Gorostas: What do you need a fiddle for?

Comment: What you have not only one form group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the documentation says:

> Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows.

It has to be interpreted in context of `row`. It means you don't put content directly in a `row` but use `columns` to layout the content. This is because, bootstrap adds a standard 15px padding on columns (first and last offsetted) to do a clean layout.

Further down the documentation says this:

> Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That
>   padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative
>   margin on `.rows`

***Note***: Now this padding is important in your use-case.

It doesn't really matter if you style your `label`s with `col-xx-` classes or wrap them in a `div` and apply `col-xx-` class to the wrapping `div`. Net effect of layout remains same.

You have provided a `background-color` for your `label`s and which is exactly why you are seeing a difference. See, when there is a label with `col-xx-` style applied, it behaves like a bootstrap column i.e. it gets 15px padding. So the label-text starts at 15px padding even though the label itself starts at the edge. However, when you wrap your `label` in a `div` and apply `col-xx-` style to the wrapping `div`, then this `div` gets the padding and the `label` starts after this padding.

This difference is what is manifesting itself visibly in your design.

***This snippet will make it clearer***: *(Notice the "Email" label which is a `label` with `col-xx-` i.e. label styled as bootstrap column. The "Password" label however is wrapped inside a `div` which as `col-xx-` style applied. Notice the difference due to padding.)*

```css
div.form-horizontal { border: 1px solid gray; }
textarea { width: 100%; }
label { background-color: silver; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br/><br/>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-horizontal col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 ">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-12">Definitie</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <textarea></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

***Here is a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/gkkwevnz/***

.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, thank you for confirming.